# Requirement to make post-pro questions non-app dependent?

Tags: discussion, questions

Lately, it seems like app requests for post pro needs (cross process and pano come to mind) are threatened with closure due to a product rec.

Years ago, it seems that these questions were not just tolerated but upvoted and answered - causing us to now have outdated product recs for post pro questions.

I'm not opposed to shortcuts (like app recommendations) but also think that **every.single.post.pro.question** should get an answer detailing how to do something using conventional methods (you know, the ones like curves, levels, layer properties...stuff that was available in image editors ten years ago and will continue to be available).

Is there any chance of forcing this requirement to make these types of questions not just more valuable but more long lived as well?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can make that a requirement, but we can certainly strive to make "generic" answers or at least answers that require and teach some understanding (and be prepared to upvote them to compensate the likely downvotes they will receive).